# Multi-table NHibernate query

Tags: nhibernate, hql, linq-to-nhibernate, icriteria, queryover

I have an object graph that looks like this:

```
class A ()
{
   int id;
   IEnumerable<B> bees;
}

class B()
{
   int id;
   A a;
   C c;
}

class C()
{
   int id;
   D d;
   IEnumerable<B> bees;
}

class D()
{
   int id;
   IEnumerable<C> cees
}
```

What would be a sensible approach for constructing a query which:

**returns a list of A types, where they contain D down the chain with a particular id?**

I'm using NH3, so can use any of the query techs.  I've tried a couple of different approaches, but have hit seemingly dead ends in each case.  I have a solution working with in memory collections - but obviously this is not ideal, I want the work done on the DB server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select distinct a from A a
inner join a.bees b
inner join b.c c
where c.d.id = :theSearchDId
```

That is assuming that all the associations are bidirectional associations, and not unrelated associations (i.e. A.bees is the inverse association of B.a, etc.).

Comment: Wow that was simple. Not really sure what confused road I was headed down.  You wouldn't happen to know if there is a simple way of returning the count of b's (or c's - same number) that link them would you?

Comment: If you mean the global number, then use select count(distinct b.id) from A a inner join a.bees b inner join b.c c where c.d.id = :theSearchDId. If you mean the number of b's per a, then use select a.id, count(distinct b.id) from A a inner join a.bees b inner join b.c c where c.d.id = :theSearchDId group by a.id